# Progress bar at every GridView element

Tags: android, gridview, progress-bar

How can I add `ProgressBar` to every single item of `GridView` in Android application? I need to have progress bar in top-right corner of `GridView` element.

Comment: Make a GridView with custom gridItems. As simple as that. See [example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/) of how to make a custom GridView. Just replace ImageView with ProgressBar and place it wherever you want to. :)

Comment: ok, i will check it out in the evening :) if I have any problems I will ask here, thanks for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom adapter, that inflates a view that contains the ProgressBar. Then during runtime you need to update the progress of the ProgressBar. Here is some really basic example to get you started.

The `row_grid_view` is just a layout that contains a progressbar. you would have to play a bit with the available layouts to see what fits your needs. A friendly warning: if the layout is part of an adapter, *do not* use a RelativeLayout. They can be really expensive to use, if you don't know what you are doing :)

The `ProgressBarAdapter` is an adapter that display a list of  `ProgressItem`s. The items contain just their own progress so that they can be used to update the progress of each ProgressBar.

row_grid_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />

</FrameLayout>
```

ProgressBarAdapter

```
public class ProgressShowingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private ArrayList<ProgressItem> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ProgressShowingAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ProgressItem getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // if your items have any unique ids, return that instead
        return position;
    }

    public void setData(List<ProgressItem> newData) {
        this.mData.clear();
        if (newData != null && !newData.isEmpty()) {
            mData.addAll(newData);
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private ProgressBar mProgress;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // view holder pattern
        ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid_view, parent, false);
            vh.mProgress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ProgressItem mItem = getItem(position);
        vh.mProgress.setProgress(mItem.getProgress());

        // do the remaining of the stuff here
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

ProgressItem

```
public class ProgressItem {
    private int mProgress;

    public ProgressItem(int mProgress) {
        this.mProgress = mProgress;
    }

    public int getProgress() {

        return mProgress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo can use this tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm
i think this will work for you